# How do I make sure that two screens only support Portrait mode?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

So, in an application that I am working on, I had to create 2 view controllers, one that would support the iPad layouts, and one that would support the iPhone layouts. However, my storyboards can't support landscape mode.

my deployment info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoNJM.jpg

part of what my info.plist looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRgku.jpg

Notice that I have iPadStoryboard.storyboard for the version that runs on iPads and Main.storyboard for the version that runs on iPhones.

The phone does what I want it to – it doesn't turn into a landscape orientation.

However, the iPad doesn't do the same thing. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only for one or two screens , Try this in your controller file

```html
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it programmatically?

In `AppDelegate.swift`,

Define `var storyboard: UIStoryboard!`

Under `func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool`

```
switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
case .phone, .unspecified:
    // It's an iPhone, or anything else like AppleWatch, AppleTV
    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
case .pad:
    // It's an iPad
    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPadStoryboard", bundle: nil)
}
```

then use this storyboard in your app to initialize your view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

on your deployment info, change devices to iPad
uncheck landscape orientation